# How to decapitalize an argument in a Live Template in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, code-snippets, live-templates

In my project, I have many serialization classes and, to make the classes more readable, I'm standardizing them, with an argument which has the same name of the `$class$`, that is `$argName$`:

```dart
@immutable
class $class$_Serialize extends Serialize<$class$> {
  final $class$ $argName$;

  $class$_Serialize(this.$argName$);

  @override
  Map<String, Object> run() => $serialize$
}
```

In the *Live Template* above, the annoyance is that I have to retype `$argName$` instead of the template simply decapitalizing `$class$`. How would I tie `$argName$` to the decapitalization of `$class$` in IntelliJ?

I've already tried to mess around with editing the variables and adding the `decaptialize()` function in the expression column, but so far haven't had much success. It was something like this:

[image: Attempt at using decapitalize()]

Comment: Could you please show how the variables are configured and where the `decaptialize` function is used?

Comment: I've added an image that hopefully offers that information. But I don't it helps anyway, there isn't much to it.

Comment: Does it help if you enable Skip if defined checkbox for argName?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for the `decapitalize` function. It should look like this:

```
decapitalize(class)
```

Note that there are no `$` signs around the `class` in the function argument.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for the help, so simple and yet it seems like it wasn't one of the variations I tried. Could you please add a link to the respective documentation for function syntax for *Live Templates*.

Comment: Just check the other live templates already available in IntelliJ IDEA for the references how to use the functions. For example, the `soutv` template.